# I cannot receieve emails even after Debugging PhpMailer

Tags: javascript, php, forms, email, phpmailer

I am using php mailer for my contact form. I am able to get a success message of the email being sent although I am not receiving the emails.
Here is my code:

contact.php

```
<form method="post" id="contactForm" action="contactProcess.php">
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="grid_6 alpha fll"><input type="text" name="senderName" id="senderName" placeholder="Name *" class="requiredField" /></div>
        <div class="grid_6 omega flr"><input type="text" name="senderEmail" id="senderEmail" placeholder="Email Address *" class="requiredField email" /></div>
    </div>
    <div><textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message *" class="requiredField" rows="8"></textarea></div>
    <input type="submit" id="sendMessage" name="sendMessage" value="Send Email" />
    <span>  </span>
</form>
```

contactProcess.php

```
<?php
include 'library.php'; // include the library file
include "classes/class.phpmailer.php"; // include the class name
if(isset($_POST["sendMessage"])){
    $name = $_POST['senderName'];
    $email = $_POST['senderEmail'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $mail   = new PHPMailer; // call the class 
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->Host = SMTP_HOST; //Hostname of the mail server
    $mail->Port = SMTP_PORT; //Port of the SMTP like to be 25, 80, 465 or 587
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; //Whether to use SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = SMTP_UNAME; //Username for SMTP authentication any valid email created in your domain
    $mail->Password = SMTP_PWORD; //Password for SMTP authentication
    $mail->From = $email;  //From address of the mail
    $mail->FromName = $name;
    $mail->Subject = ("Mail From Contact Form"); //Subject of your mail

    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->AddAddress("me@add.com");//To address who will receive this email
    $mail->AddCC("add@add.com");
    $mail->AddReplyTo("add2@add.com", "Me");
    $mail->Body = $message;
    $mail->AltBody = $message;

    $send = $mail->Send(); //Send the mails
    if($send){ ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('sent');
        window.location = 'contact.php';
    </script>
    <?php
    }
    else{ ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed');
        window.location = 'contact.php';
    </script>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

and finally the ajax validation script:
main.js

```
// Ajax Contact
if ($("#contactForm")[0]) {
    $('#contactForm').submit(function () {
        $('#contactForm .error').remove();
        $('.requiredField').removeClass('fielderror');
        $('.requiredField').addClass('fieldtrue');
        $('#contactForm span strong').remove();
        var hasError = false;
        $('#contactForm .requiredField').each(function () {
            if (jQuery.trim($(this).val()) === '') {
                var labelText = $(this).prev('label').text();
                $(this).addClass('fielderror');
                $('#contactForm span').html('<strong>*Please fill out all fields.</strong>');
                hasError = true;
            } else if ($(this).hasClass('email')) {
                var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
                if (!emailReg.test(jQuery.trim($(this).val()))) {
                    var labelText = $(this).prev('label').text();
                    $(this).addClass('fielderror');
                    $('#contactForm span').html('<strong>Your email address is incorrect</strong>');
                    hasError = true;
                }
            }
        });
        if (!hasError) {
            $('#contactForm').slideDown('normal', function () {
                $("#contactForm #sendMessage").addClass('load-color');
                $("#contactForm #sendMessage").attr("disabled", "disabled").val('Sending message. Please wait...');
            });
            var formInput = $(this).serialize();
            $.post($(this).attr('action'), formInput, function (data) {
                $('#contactForm').slideUp("normal", function () {
                    $(this).before('<div class="notification-box notification-box-success"><p><i class="icon-ok"></i>Thanks!</strong> Your email was successfully sent. We will get back to you soonest!.</p></div>');
                });
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

I have tried to setting $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; and also include error_reporting(E_ALL); in hope that i could get any errors but nothing happens.

Any ideas, please!

Comment: Do you have any access to the mail logs in your web server? You might have a problem with the local mailer configuration, and those mails could be accepted locally but not leaving your websrv. If you are working on a Linux/UNIX server, and you have access to a shell console on it, try sending one using the "mail" command, and see if it gets to the destination.

Comment: Unfortunately, i do not have any access to the mail logs as am on a shared windows server.  Is there way around it?

Comment: i have had contact with my hosting solution and they say that they have tested the mail service of that account through the webmail and it is working fine so it has to be something with the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code on my server, setting the SMTP_* values accordingly. In my case, the host was "localhost", port 25, and SMTP Auth "false". The message was properly queued.

So my guess is that there is an issue with the mailer settings. Check that all the SMTP_* values (which I assume you are setting on library.php or in a file included by it) are correct.

Commenting the `window.location()` call, I was able to see this output from SMTP debugging.

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 220 <server name edited> ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-<server name edited> 250-PIPELINING 250-SIZE 10240000 250-VRFY 250-ETRN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-8BITMIME 250 DSN
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250 2.1.0 Ok
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250 2.1.5 Ok
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 354 End data with .
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as C39A6440AA
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 221 2.0.0 Bye
```

To sum up, your code seems OK, you may have a configuration issue.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ Mariano: Yes,i am setting the smtp values in the library.php and i want to believe i am using the right values as I have counter checked them thoroughly. Unless,the SMTP_USNAME which in my case is another mail account i have set up is not the right value to use.(I have set it: hello@add.com and am using The password for the email account as SMTP_PASSWORD)...do u suppose that is the problem?if not, My only other concern now is that u said tht u've used SMTP Auth "false"..should i change mine from SMTP Auth "true" to SMTP Auth "false"? Again,thanks a bunch for all ur support!

Comment: @Josealonso14, it all depends on the server settings. In my test, auth wasn't necessary, but that is not usually the case with production servers. Even so, as your code worked just by changing the config, I suggest you try running it on another server (maybe setting up a local LAMP/WAMP on your machine?), or using another mail provider, or even both.